# Anti frost faucet leak

Tags: plumbing, faucet

This faucet was installed last summer, strange leak through holes in stem.. any idea what is causing this?  Can it be fixed??

[image][image]

Comment: can't see where leak is actually occurring. can you post a side picture?

Comment: sure.. there are 2 small holes on the stem.. will post another pic shortly.

Comment: Added the side view .. any ideas?

Comment: Anti Frost type faucets have the valve turn on/off gate well inside the exterior wall. When the faucet is shut off the water left in the outside portion of the valve has to drain out. It could be that the "leaking" you are seeing is this water draining out. Please clarify in your question if you are seeing the "leaking" when the faucet is ON, when the faucet has just turned OFF or if the faucet has been OFF for a long time and the hose is detached.

Comment: Leaking out both holes when the faucet is on..

Comment: What make and model faucet?

Comment: I have never seen a faucet with a hollow stem, much less one with two holes in the stem through which water dribbles when the valve is open! What could possibly be the purpose of such a design? This must be a specialty valve that should not have been installed as an outside faucet for a residence.  Perhaps there is a plug which inserts in and blocks the two holes in the stem? Perhaps there is a valve inside the stem which can be positioned to block the flow out of these two holes.

Comment: If the valve is opened all the way and tightened firmly against the stop, does the flow out the two holes in the stem stop?

Comment: This is not your model, but appears the have the [same design](http://www.arrowheadbrass.net/Images/Web/Repair/420.pdf). That is a weep hole and indicates (if leaking during normal use) a worn out o-ring in the check assembly.

Comment: I have seen these before they require "adjustment" of the packing so when the valve is opened they seal off. When closed they allow the water in the stem area to drain. I found out about them the hard way I saw the leak and tightened the handle just a bit two much and it snapped off. The advantage to this design is it will drain with a hose attached so the freezing water won't break the valve.

Answer (score 1):

From your side view it looks like there may be a minor leak around the valve stem just behind the faucet handle. You can investigate this by first removing the faucet handle. Then loosen and remove the part pointed to below:

[image]

(Do this with the faucet initially shut OFF).

Under this part you should find a rubber type part that fits around the valve stem. When this part is screwed in tighter it will compress the rubber part around the valve stem to keep it from leaking.

Sometimes with age this rubber type part will get hard or cracked so that it can no longer provide a good seal against the valve stem. In this case it is necessary to replace the rubber part.

There are also cases where the valve stem itself can get oxidized and/or corroded to the point that it no longer presents a nice smooth surface to the rubber seal part. It may be necessary to shine up the valve stem using a fine grade of steel wool.

Sometimes it can be beneficial to lubricate the valve stem and inner surface of the rubber type seal part using some petroleum jelly.

Comment: The water is coming direch

Comment: The water is coming directly out of those small pin holes

Comment: I know on my hydrant style freeze proofs the valve needs to be fully opened to block the drain port this valve may require the same to block water from getting to the drains in the valve stem. Or tighting the packing nut may help since its only a year old I wouldn't think the packing would have broken down already.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take the faucet apart to find out how the water is getting into the hollow valve stem.

Remove the handle and remove the packing nut. Use a pipe wrench to apply counter torque to the faucet body while loosening the packing nut; this avoids stressing the attachment of the faucet to your house.

Pull out the valve stem and valve assembly. Fish out, or flush out, any loose parts that remain behind.

The operation of the check valve, washer, and seat may not be obvious, mainly because you're examining one that's not working properly. See if the manufacturer's web site has any documentation or diagrams.

Post pics of the disassembled innards.